Google Sheet API Timeout
Since last week, I've been experiencing timeout issues when reading or updating sheets using the Google Sheets API. Recently, it has gotten worse, and sometimes it's unavailable for hours. I'm not sure what's causing this issue.
for read
public List<List<Object>> getSpreadsheetValue(String spreadsheetId, String dataRange) {
        List<List<Object>> values = null;
        try {
            Sheets sheetsService = getRandomService();
            ValueRange response = sheetsService.spreadsheets().values()
                    .get(spreadsheetId, dataRange)
                    .execute();
            values = response.getValues();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return values;
    }

for write
public void batchUpdate(String spreadsheetId, String range, List<List<Object>> values) {
        Sheets sheetsService = getRandomService();
        ValueRange requestBody = new ValueRange().setValues(values);
        try {
            UpdateValuesResponse response = sheetsService.spreadsheets().values()
                    .update(spreadsheetId, range, requestBody)
                    .setValueInputOption(ValueInputOption.USER_ENTERED.toString())
                    .execute();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("update google sheet failed ,{}", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

error message
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:476)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readHeader(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:470)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.bytesInCompletePacket(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:70)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1369)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.access$300(SSLSocketImpl.java:73)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:978)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:743)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:678)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1600)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1505)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:352)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpResponse.<init>(NetHttpResponse.java:36)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:149)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:84)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1012)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:514)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:455)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:565)
    at com.kikatech.earning.utils.GoogleSheetUtils.getSpreadsheetValue(GoogleSheetUtils.java:317)

My sheet has the following characteristics:

There are no formulas or external data imports. The sheet contains fewer than 500 rows, with each row having no more than 30 columns. The cells contain simple numbers, and each operation only reads or updates the most recent rows.

Updates are frequent, approximately every 20 minutes.

The sheet is referenced by other sheets.


This program has been running stably for over a year without issues, but problems started two weeks ago and are getting worse. I've tried the following:

I confirmed that there are no network issues with my server. Timeouts occur in different server environments, including locally.

When I copy this sheet to a new sheet and operate on the new one, there are no timeout issues.

The timeout does not relate to the amount of data being read or written. Even reading a single cell results in a timeout when it occurs.


I received suggestions that frequent updates might accumulate a lot of history and could cause this issue, but I'm still confused. Has anyone encountered similar problems? I appreciate any suggestions.

This is isolated case and in your current situation its not pointing towards on your code it might be towards on some isolated issue you can direct or check on  this link if the case have the same issue like yours.
